# GET urls and application state in the playframework

Tags: playframework

Is there a way to give my links all variables in an object?  The purpose of this is to make the links book-markable.  The important information to re-build the screen will all be in the URL.

My work-around introduces a session and url re-writing.  This is a link that will add or change the industry variable in my object `s`:

```
<a href="@{Stocks.index()}?s.industry=${roeBean.industry?.urlEncode()}">
```

When the link is clicked, Stocks.index is called accepting the object `s` as its parameter.  That receives the s.industry data and all other values in `s` are null.  So, I can then merge the `s` parameter with another copy of `s` saved in the session.  The cache is then updated and the URL re-written.

It works great, but it would be more elegant if the play framework had something to simply expand the state object and change a variable (just for the link).  Is there an clean way to do this?  I imaging this would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would just creating a new controller method (not index) for the purpose of just updating industry work? The follow will work when passed the s.id and the s.industry to be added (or if exists replaced if that's what you're looking to do).

In your view:
(send the view the s object but it seems like you do that now) (also, I'm using the groovy template helper, you can use the html if you want, same results)

```
#{a @Stocks.index(s.id, s.industry=roeBean.industry) } Add This Industry {/a}
```

In your controller:
(Replace String with whatever Industry is)

```
public static void addIndustry(Long id, String industry) {
    Stock s = Search.findById(id);
    String i = industry;
    //Do your stuff
    s.save();
}
```

Passing a static string here (or other stuff) works too. so s.industry='test' will GET id=1 and industry=test in this example.

If you want your links to have all properties of an object, can you not just send the whole object? Passing the entire key/value bit of every property in an object seems like a lot of work if you just want the entire object? So in this example:

when you render the view from your controller

```
render(s);
```

the link?

```
#{a @Stocks.index(s, s.industry=roeBean.industry) } Add This Industry {/a}
```

In your controller to save:

```
public static void addIndustry(Stock s, String industry) {
    //Do your stuff
    s.save();
}
```

Comment: I clarified my question.  Thanks for using the #{a syntax, I'll upgrade my habit right away.

Comment: Updated answer, against still a bit unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: You can close the as like this `#{/a}`...  I tried the much better looking syntax above, but the URL resolves to `s=` instead of `s.industry=` (example: `s=Trucks+%26+Other+Vehicles`).  Additionally, `industry=` resolves to `s=` .. I guess Play 1.5 is not matching on the public variables in that object.  I'll try your additional examples a bit later.  thanks...

Comment: You helped build a better mouse trap.  I made a modification though.  I created a controller method Stocks.industry(s, industry) and called that.  Play resolved all of the URLs.  I called `index` in the controller so Play re-wrote the URL for me.  This is an improvement as I don't need the session anymore, the links have all the state.  The template syntax cleaner.  I just have the overhead of extra methods in the controller.  This is a better work-around.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error! Can you post your code in your question (use a heading like "Solution" in bold), I'm curious what you ended up with, others probably are too, and I'm sure it's me not understanding (long weekend!)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have entity S in the database and you want to change only s.industry value in this entity.

If along with **s.industry** you add **s.id** parameter then Play! will get S entity with this id from database and will merge in the parameters that you pass in URL.
So, for the link like this:

```
<a href="@{Stocks.index()}?s.industry=${roeBean.industry?.urlEncode()}&s.id=1">
```

The following will happen. Play will get S object with id=1, then it will set **industry** value that you passed as URL parameter, and after that *Stocks.index* method will get merged S object.

Comment: I had to clarify my question quite a bit (see above).  Thanks for your feedback, this helped.